# Loading fonts into ImageFont from GCS

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, python-imaging-library

I am having problems loading fonts in memory, directly from GCS, without creating temporary files.

The goal is to load it into:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket_name'
gs_path = 'path_in_bucket/object.otf'
font_file = load_font_from_gcs(gs_path)
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_file, 18)
```

I tried using the following 2 functions to download:

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()

def load_font_from_gcs(gs_path):
    font_file = download_blob_as_string(gs_path)
    return font_file

def download_blob_as_string(source_blob_name, bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket as string."""

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    return blob.download_as_string()
```

However, I keep running into encoding/decoding errors or type errors e.g.

> File
>   "/anaconda3/envs/ml36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py",
>   line 161, in **init**
>       font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine=layout_engine TypeError: argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not
>   bytes

Comment: The `download_as_string()` function, as its name does not imply, returns bytes (see https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_as_string). Maybe your issue is related?

Comment: I know that it returns bytes, the thing is that `PIL/ImageFont.py` should process bytes. I think there is a bug in logic since if platform != win32, we do not use the bytes anywhere

Comment: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/1cecf08d16509c20473766b4cdb7a65169844819/src/PIL/ImageFont.py#L188 This line should be ```self.font = core.getfont(
                "", size, index, encoding, self.font_bytes, layout_engine
            )```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping it in a BytesIO works on my Mac:

```
from io import BytesIO
...
...
font_file = load_font_from_gcs(gs_path)
font = ImageFont.truetype(BytesIO(font_file), 18)
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there a difference between the 2 bytes objects?

Comment: I don't know, sorry! I only know from experience that the `BytesIO` thing works well where files are expected!