# Using PIL, How do I point the “fonts” to its referenced file on GCF

Tags: google-cloud-functions, python-imaging-library

I am using PIL on cloud function
How do I point the “fonts” to that file.

I wonder shall I save the “fonts file” to the cloud storage and point the path? Any ideas or comments will be appreciated. Than you!

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont
From Google.cloud import storage


storage_client = storage.Client()
. . . . . .

with blob.open() as file:
   img = Image.open(file)                 


draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("simsun.ttc", 18).  ## <- the font here
. . . . . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PIL does not have the built-in ability to automatically open files from GCS. you will need to either:

- Download the file to local storage and point PIL to that file or
- Give PIL a BlobReader which it can use to access the data

You will have to use the reference path for the file and call the same in the code import function , example code as below:

```
font_file = load_font_from_gcs(gs_path)
font = ImageFont.truetype(BytesIO(font_file), 11)
```

Check the following helpful links with similar implementation:

- [GCS Python way to list certain folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398898/google-cloud-storage-python-any-way-to-list-obj-in-certain-folder-in-gcs/22399617#22399617)
- [Read and write file from gcs via python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70150986/read-and-write-images-from-gcs-via-python-flask)
- [Loading fonts and images from gcs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60266788/loading-fonts-into-imagefont-from-gcs)
- [Loading font from url to pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64708802/loading-font-from-url-to-pillow)